# Woocommerce remove view cart from all pages, including home page?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm making a website with woocommerce. My target is not retail selling but wholesaling. I am using "Request a Quote" as a wholesale inquiry cart. The problem is that I don't need "view cart" option which is visible in the top right corner on every page. I still need shopping cart functionality in order to "Request A Quote" keep working.

[Here is the picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7prMs.jpg) You can see it on top right corner.

Is there any custom CSS code that could remove it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do with `css`:

```
.top-bar-mini-cart{
        display: none;
}
```